# Why are the MonoBehaviour methods not implemented for overriding?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In `Unity3d` you have the `MonoBehaviour` class, which is the normal base class for all scripts. When implementing a script, one has to implement the methods such as `Awake()` or `Start()` or `Update()`.

However, These methods are not implemented as `virtual` or `abstract` in the `MonoBehaviour` class so that one could easily `override` them; in fact they are not implemented at all. The method one writes at the Moment is a new method that the class did not have beforehand.

Why are these methods not implemented as `virtual` or `abstract` in the base class (`MonoBehaviour`)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you check the documentation you will see that all those 'functions' are listed in the 'Messages' section; [MonoBehaviour Doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).

So that means that 'functions' (like Start, OnEnable or Awake), they are not implemented as methods but as messages.

Now, MonoBehaviour inherits from [Behaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html), which inherits from [Component](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) which has the [SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html) method. That method basically calls a message/method with the option to report an error if the message/method exists or not. The parameter of the name message/method is a string, /~~*so they are using reflection there*.~~/ **Check Update!!**

Seems like Unity behind the scenes determines if those messages were implemented to see if it has to call them or not. According to this [UnityAnswer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/177245/how-does-unitys-built-in-event-system-work-behind.html):

> Unity is mainly written in c++ and therefore most magic happens in
> native code. Unity uses reflection to determine, after your scripts
> have been compiled, what of those "events" you've implemented and
> remember that for this class. Unity only calls Update / LateUpdate /
> OnGUI when it has been implemented.

So, the short answer is, they are not 'real' methods that you have to override, they are messages that are called only if they were implemented.

---

**Update**;
As @Raining noted, I was wrong in the way that Unity obtains the messages to call.
Unity doesn't use reflection to do this.
According this [1k-update-calls](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/) (also provided by @Rainin) scripts are inspected to check if they contain some of those 'magic methods'. If so, they are added to lists that will be executed accordingly.

Comment: Just a note, Unity doesn't use reflection.

Comment: hi @Raining, could you add more info about that? So I can update the answer with the right information! Thanks!

Comment: You could read this post: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/ And thanks for your willing to update : ) This mindset makes this forum better.

Comment: Thank you!! and thanks for the link and the clarification!