# Is it normal that 'private' function like Start, Update of the parent class is called in a child class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it normal that 'private' function like Start, Update of the parent class is called in the child class?

For example

Script Parent :

```
public class Parent : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Awake Parent");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Start Parent");
    }
}
```

Script Child :

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    // nothing
}
```

When I add Child script as a component to any gameobject, then "Awake Parent" and "Start Parent" appear on Unity console window.

But, the Awake and Start functions are private now. I know private method can't be derived. Is it right?

Then why that private functions are called in this situation?

Comment: "I know private method can't be derived" Not true. They are of course **inherited**, however you can´t **access** them. So the base-class can of course call it, only child-classes can *not*.

Comment: So where are they called from?

Comment: Unity calls methods like this implicitly, with reflection.

Comment: Look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventFunctions.html) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) those methods are called "Messages". They use a Unity internal system similar to events.

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question with great answers but I can't find it. The access modifier used with the built-n callback functions doesn't matter. Unity will still call them.

Comment: @JonSkeet : AFAIK, Unity does not use reflection to call the "magic" methods (MonoBehaviour's messages) (see [How Update is called](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/))

Comment: @Hellium: That says it doesn't use reflection *every time it needs to call* such a method. The description sounds to me like it uses reflection to find which methods are declared, and probably creates a delegate to each one in order to call it efficiently. I think that's sufficiently close to "via reflection" to count in the context of this question - although I admit my description was very simplistic.

Comment: Thank you all for great comments. It was good chance to study C# and Unity about what I didn't know.

Comment: This is another related question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537997/why-are-the-monobehaviour-methods-not-implemented-for-overriding/32541157#32541157